# How to specify namespace and schema location in an XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

My goal is to create an XML that is correctly referencing an XSD file describing the structure while both files use namespaces (the XML by setting the default namespace in the `xmlns` attribute).

I can specify `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute in the XML and it works at least in some validators (like http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/). But when I try to add namespaces the validator returns errors (like: Can not find declaration of element 'note'.)

The final versions of the test files I prepared are attached below. I tested it with `xmllint` like:

```
xmllint example.xml --schema example.xsd
```

and it worked, but I specified the schema location in a parameter. My question is: is the XML file correctly referring the XSD and is it correctly using the namespace? Why the validator returns an error?

example.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="example.xsd"
        xmlns="http://example/note"
>
        <from>Jacek</from>
        <to>Agatka</to>
        <body>Kocham cię!</body>
</note>
```

example.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns="http://example/note"
       targetNamespace="http://example/note"
>
       <xsd:element name="note">
               <xsd:complexType>
                       <xsd:sequence>
                               <xsd:element ref="from"/>
                               <xsd:element ref="to"/>
                               <xsd:element ref="body"/>
                       </xsd:sequence>
               </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>

      <xsd:element name="from" type="xsd:string"/>

      <xsd:element name="to" type="xsd:string"/>

      <xsd:element name="body" type="xsd:string"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `schemaLocation` attribute should specify also the namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<note
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://example/note example.xsd"
  xmlns="http://example/note">
  <from>Jacek</from>
  <to>Agatka</to>
  <body>Kocham cię!</body>
</note>
```

See documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256100.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! At least Validome started accepting my example. Anyway it's a bit strange: I declare the namespace twice -- once in the schema file and once in the XML. It seems redundant and serving no purpose, because the validator doesn't permit me to rename the namespace in the XML (like `xsi:schemaLocation="http://example/note2 example.xsd" xmlns="http://example/note2"`)